# Submit button to pass value to database and show the occurences of the value(laravel)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, submit-button, find-occurrences

I'm new at programming, especially at laravel. I've tried a lot and now I try to make laravel project but get stuck at some problems.

I want to make the submit button to pass data to the database and find out the occurences of the value in the radio button. I managed to pass data to the database but I still can't find a solution to find occurences. So, how can I know the occurences when the submit button was clicked?

Here is the blade (**question.blade.php**)

```
<table class="table" style="width: 40%">

<form action="storequestion" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<tr>
    <th>M</th>
    <th>Question 1</th>
    <th>L</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="S" data-col="1"></td>
    <td>1.Statement</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="S" data-col="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="I" data-col="2"></td>
    <td>2.Statement</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="I" data-col="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="B" data-col="3"></td>
    <td>3.Statement</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="D" data-col="3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="C" data-col="4"></td>
    <td>4.Statement</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="C" data-col="4"></td>
</tr>

        <tr>
            <th>M</th>
            <th>Question 2</th>
            <th>L</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="q3" value="D" data-col="5"></td>
            <td>5.Statement</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="q4" value="D" data-col="5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="q3" value="C" data-col="6"></td>
            <td>6.Statement</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="q4" value="C" data-col="6"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="q3" value="B" data-col="7"></td>
            <td>7.Statement</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="q4" value="I" data-col="7"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="q3" value="B" data-col="8"></td>
            <td>8.Statement</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="q4" value="S" data-col="8"></td>
        </tr>

<tr> <td> <br><br> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> </td></tr>

</form>
</table>
```

Here is the controller (**tanswercontroller.php**)

```
public function storequestion(Request $request)
{
    $tanswer = new tanswer;
    $tanswer->q1 = $request->q1;
    $tanswer->q2 = $request->q2;
    $tanswer->q3 = $request->q3;
    $tanswer->q4 = $request->q4;
    $tanswer->save();
    return 'data saved';
 }
```

Here is the route (**web.php**)

```
route::post('/storequestion', 'tanswercontroller@storequestion');
```

So, when the submit button clicked it shows the occurence of the value of radio button checked which is a string so then it will give output something like this

```
//suppose we choose the radio button who has:
//in Question 1
//name="q1" value="S" data-col="1"
//name="q2" value="I" data-col="2"

//In Question 2
//name="q3" value="B" data-col="7"
//name="q4" value="S" data-col="8"

//The result will show
// S = 2 , I = 1 , B = 1
```

Please help me to solve this problem. If you think using javascript is easier, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: when you want to show this result because in your question is not clarify.

Comment: hello, @AjayDeepakKumar! Thank you for remind me. I already edit the question. I need to calculate it when we hit the submit button.

Comment: here i understood suppose you have selected all question's answer then clicked on submit button then you need to show result after calculation like fail or pass or something else

Comment: you're right @AjayDeepakKumar but the result must be the total of string appear just like S=2 , I=1 , B=1. It's like counting the occurences of string inputed

Comment: then you can use ajax or any other http request library to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i understood you can do this like this way.

first you have to create a route

```
route::get('/result', 'tanswercontroller@result');
```

then in `tanswercontroller.php`

modify your `storequestion()` method and add `result()` method

**tanswercontroller.php**

```
class tanswercontroller extends Controller
{

    /*
    * for storing data then redirected to result 
    * page with id you can make token for this 
    * if you prefer 
    */ 
    public function storequestion(Request $request)
    {
        // you must validate data like ---
        // $this->validate($request, ['q1' => 'required', ...]);

        $tanswer = new tanswer;
        $tanswer->q1 = $request->q1;
        $tanswer->q2 = $request->q2;
        $tanswer->q3 = $request->q3;
        $tanswer->q4 = $request->q4;
        $tanswer->save();

        // redirect to result page with id
        return redirect()->url('result/'.$tanswer->id); // added this line
    }


    public function result($id)
    {
        // pulling data of answer for calulation 
        $tanswer = tanswer::find($id);

        // do some calulation here the return data like 
        $result = //yourCalculation;

        /*
        * now calculation is stored in result variable then 
        * passing result in view so show result as you wish
        */
        return view('result', ['result' => $result]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you will need :

```
$value = $request->q1 - $request->q2;
```

This will store the result in the variable `$value`.

Comment: It won't do because the value is string. In other words I need to find the occurence of the strings. Ex: S=2 , I=1 , B=1